# How can I update a window position and size from `awakeFromNib`?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This code makes my app to crash because `awakeFromNib` is invoked recursively:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
        ...
        [[self window] setFrameTopLeftPoint:NSMakePoint(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y)];
}
```

Is setFrameTopLeftPoint invoking `awakeFromNib` again ? I thought awakeFromNib is invoked only once, when the NSWindow is loaded by the XIB file.

How can I update a window position and size from `awakeFromNib` ?

thanks

Comment: in what class are you declaring this awakeFromNib ?

Comment: @Denis In the NSWindowController, which is the delegate of the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're getting infinite recursion in awakeFromNib. I created a test project mimicking your code and -awakeFromNib was only called once. I suspect it has something to do with the way you're initializing your window controller.

That said, updating the window position would probably be better done in -windowDidLoad. From the "Subclassing NSWindowController" section of the docs, it says:

> windowDidLoad: Override to perform tasks after the window nib file is
>   loaded.